# primeng make work the filter in a table using a dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, filtering, dropdown, primeng-table

I have a p-table from primeng
and try to match the selection from the dropdown and make work the filter method from table but i don't acomplish

```
<p-table
    #customTable
    id="customTable"
    [value]="allCustomConfig$ | async"
    [paginator]="(allCustomConfig$ | async)?.length > 10"
    [rows]="10"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"
    selectionMode="single"
    [scrollable]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr class="tr-head-title">
        <th scope="col" class="th-title-actions">
          {{ 'features.masters.analytics_config.table.actions' | translate }}
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="th-title-custom">
          {{ 'features.masters.analytics_config.table.analytics' | translate }}
          <!-- <p-sortIcon field="analytics"></p-sortIcon> -->
        </th>
        <th scope="col" pSortableColumn="translation" class="th-title-translation">
          {{ 'features.masters.analytics_config.table.translation' | translate }}
          <p-sortIcon field="translation"></p-sortIcon>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">
          <p-dropdown
            (onClear)="filterTable()"
            (onHide)="filterTable()"
            [(ngModel)]="CustomConfigSelect"
            [options]="customDropdown"
            optionLabel="analytics"
            [placeholder]="'features.masters.analytics_config.modal.analytics_placeholder' | translate"
            [showClear]="true"
            filterMode="contains">
          </p-dropdown>
        </th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-config>
      <tr class="tr-body">
        <td class="td-buttons">
          <button
            (click)="editCustomConfigModal(config)"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-outlined p-button-warning btn"
            icon="pi pi-pencil"
            pButton
            type="button"></button>
          <button
            (click)="deleteCustomConfig(config)"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-outlined p-button-danger btn"
            style="margin-left: 10px"
            icon="pi pi-trash"
            pButton
            type="button"></button>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ config?.featureFaultDescription?.analytics }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ config?.translation }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- Empty Message -->
    <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
      <tr>
        <!-- <td colspan="6">No custom configurations found.</td> -->
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</p-card>
```

and this method in my class component

```
public customDropdown: FeatureFaultDescription[] = [
   { analytics: 'string a', featureFaultDescriptionId: 1 },
   { analytics: 'string b', featureFaultDescriptionId: 2 },
   { analytics: 'string c', featureFaultDescriptionId: 3 },
   { analytics: 'string e', featureFaultDescriptionId: 4 }
 ];
public CustomConfigSelect: FeatureFaultDescription;


public filterTable(): void {
   if (this.CustomConfigSelect) {
     this.table?.filter(
       this.CustomConfigSelect,
       'CustomConfigSelect',
       'contains'
     );
   } else {
     this.table.reset();
   }
 }
```

do you see where is the problem?

i try to match the selection from dropdown in the   <ng-template pTemplate="header">

```
       <p-dropdown
            (onClear)="filterTable()"
            (onHide)="filterTable()"
            [(ngModel)]="CustomConfigSelect"
            [options]="customDropdown"
            optionLabel="analytics"
            [placeholder]="'features.masters.analytics_config.modal.analytics_placeholder' |  
            translate"
            [showClear]="true"
            filterMode="contains">
       </p-dropdown>
```

so in the table can display only the one i select

Answer (score 0):

1. replace options interface from `{ analytics: string, featureFaultDescriptionId: number }` to `{label: string, value: any}`
2. showClear should be `"CustomConfigSelect"` rather than solid `"true"`
3. try to trigger `filterTable` function with `onChange` event of dropdown component
4. use the emitted event like `filterTable($event)` to filter table, not `this.CustomConfigSelect`

besides, the version of primeng should be provided. It helps troubleshooting.

Comment: here's the official doc https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v8-lts/#/table

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is working perfectly now

```
public filterTable(): void {
    if (this.FeatureFaultDescriptionSelect) {
      this.table?.filter(
        this.FeatureFaultDescriptionSelect?.featureFaultDescriptionId,
        'featureFaultDescription.featureFaultDescriptionId',
        'contains'
      );
    } else {
      this.table.reset();
    }
  }
```

even is working like this

```
this.table?.filter(
        this.FeatureFaultDescriptionSelect?.analytics,
        'featureFaultDescription.analytics',
        'contains'
      );
```

inside the method filter from table the  value and the field should match

```
Table.filter(value: any, field: string, matchMode: string):
```